# bootsrap get back results from modal popup to each line?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with multiple lines,
each line user can select the gender, I would like to assign the gender to the appropriate input on the same line,

I don't have a unique identifier for each row because they are added dynamically..
Is it possible to do without unique identifier for each button/input?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> gender: <input type="text" name="gender">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  select gender
</button> <br/>

 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> gender: <input type="text" name="gender">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  select gender
</button><br/>

 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"> gender: <input type="text" name="gender">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  select gender
</button><br/>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other  
</form> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer for your question is "of course you can", but this is not a good practice, 
I've tried to write some code and u can take a look it [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/static-c8t1q?fontsize=14), what I did here are:

1. declaring a variable called "globalVariable" then assign the modal button row into that variable when it is clicked since u not add a unique key to each row, and clear it every time the modal get hide.
2. assign the "globalVariable" value to the column by searching it through its tr